# Chrome OS and Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, google-chrome, chromebook, chromeos

I started using Ubuntu a few weeks ago, so I decided to install it also on my Chromebook. It feels so nice, but I get this error when I try to update Ubuntu:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

The problem is I didn't installed Chrome at all in Ubuntu, I have the bad feeling that the Chrome OS is troubleshooting it (Even it is in dual boot an should be on its own partition). Also Wine cannot be installed.

The forum has some answers for the error, but I just started with Ubuntu so it would be nice if you could help me.

So how to fix it and is Chrome OS the problem? Is it not properly installed?

Last night I installed it 3 times and I already fixed the update problem. (in the settings of the Software Center there were 2 indentical links for updates, I just deleted one), but Wine still doesn't work

Like Andrew mentioned, I believe Wine wants the 32-bit version, but I have the HP 14 Chromebook which is definitely 64-bit and I installed 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 lts!

The error says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the 
unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[Wine Issues with Installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471083/wine-issues-with-installing)

There seems to be a solution, but I dont want to install the 32 bit on my 64bit???
Isnt that a kind of "downgrading"? Doesnt that cause more Problems?

Answer (score 0):

As for Wine, most Chromebooks use an ARM architecture, so a program that is 32-bit or 64-bit will not work. (Please provide your Chromebook's architecture to help me help you.)

As for the updates, open up a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get update` (the code in the bottom of the output you posted). This should fix the problem.

As for ChromeOS, Unless you're doing a Ubuntu overlay on ChromeOS, there shouldn't be any problem in Ubuntu relating to ChromeOS.

Comment: well in the last night I installed it 3 times and I already fixe the updateproblem...(in the settings of the softwarecenter there were 2 indentic links for updates, I just deleted one)
But wine still doesnt work

Comment: I added more information in the original post, also thx fpr your help=)