# Wine Issues with Installing

Tags: wine

I can't install Wine 1.6 on my 14.04 Ubuntu install. I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It doesn't works on me.<br/>
Using Ubuntu 14.04 x64.<br/>
And still showing this : > The following packages have unmet dependencies: > wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)<br/>
> Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed<br/>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Still looking for solutions...

Comment: First this is a unmet dependency error which i have added as duplicate to the correct question.  Second please follow my wine guide to properly install and configure wine.  With both of this questions you should be well on your way on having wine working in no time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the i386 architecture.  You can add it and then install wine like so:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```