# Wine installation on Ubuntu 14.04 failed

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine, package-management, dpkg

Installation of wine failed, since migration on Ubuntu 14.04 (from 12.04).

I precise that i have tried many things commonly suggest including :

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge wine -f
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

but it doesn't works ....

Errors :

```
sudo apt-get install wine
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
wine : Dépend: wine1.6 mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».


sudo apt-get install wine1.6
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
wine1.6 : Dépend: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode «   garder en l'état ».



sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
wine1.6-i386:i386 : Dépend: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wine Issues with Installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471083/wine-issues-with-installing)

Comment: You need to add the i386 arch. Open a terminal and execute the following commands one-by-one: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

Comment: It doesn't works for me. Which is the result for
    sudo dpkg --print-architecture
after run
    dpkg --add-architecture i386

Answer (score 2):

I found !
i install the offical liblcms2-2 trusty 14.04 version :

```
sudo apt-get install liblcms2-2=2.5-0ubuntu4
```

after install of wine works !

more details :
http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=18152341#p18152341

Comment: Installing the official liblcms2-2 trusty 14.04 version did it for me. After that I could install wine which was not possible before.
Thank you for your help. I have been looking for days to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes experienced these issues when I forgot to update the package lists before installing. I don't know if you've already tried this, but make sure that you run the following command before installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
```