# Cannot Install Wine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine

I would like to run Windows Programs ".exe" with Wine on my Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I am 15 and new to the Ubuntu OS and it's environment and for some reason I can't download the Wine Program Installer.
Here is what my terminal says:

```
(trusty)james@localhost:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
[sudo] password for james: 
 Welcome to the Wine Team PPA.  Here you can get the latest available Wine betas for every supported version of Ubuntu.  This PPA is managed by Scott Ritchie and Maarten Lankhorst.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpps8ia136/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpps8ia136/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpps8ia136/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key F9CB8DB0: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
(trusty)james@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                        
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                     
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                     
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                      
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                      
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse armhf Packages           
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages          
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                  
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en                
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources [17.6 kB]                   
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en          
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages [9079 B]             
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en          
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [20.4 kB]             
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                     
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [10.8 kB]            
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources [21.6 kB]                   
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages [14.9 kB]            
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [15.8 kB]             
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [5429 B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted armhf Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe armhf Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                   
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse armhf Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                        
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                             
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 131 kB in 27s (4758 B/s)                                               
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.151 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
(trusty)james@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                Depends: wine1.7-i386:i386 (= 1:1.7.55-0ubuntu1)
                Recommends: fonts-droid:i386
                Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont:i386
                Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core:i386
                Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: First you really should file a bug against that wine ppa and second if you search on this site you will find this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wine Issues with Installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471083/wine-issues-with-installing)

Comment: Easy step by step instructions link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Answer (score 0):

*Your repositories is a mess you have repositories even for different architecture so lets clean that mess.*

**Open "Ubuntu Software Center"**

Edit Menu

**Select** "Software Sources...", enter your password

**Click** "Other Software"

From the "Other Software" tab you can **add** or **remove** repositories that dont work such as for ex: ***http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages*** which is for **ARM** (armhf) architecture.

Also delete repositories that saying **404  Not Found** in your terminal.

*Now type in your terminal:*

**sudo apt-get remove wine1.7**

**sudo apt-get autoremove**

**sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa**

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get upgrade**

Now reboot your pc.

**Optional:** *You can remove the wine folder that contains your .dll's and .exe's program files etc, if you want a fresh install. (recommended)*

Go to directory **/home/james** from your file manager and click to **view your hidden folders**, the file is **.wine** just delete that.

Install **Winetricks** from Ubuntu software center.

Now go to the official wine page:
**https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu**

And follow the instructions to install the latest **stable** or **release** version of wine.

*If you cant find the shortcut of wine after the installation just type in the terminal* **winecfg**

Now find out what you need to install from **Winetricks** according to what program or game you want to use.